# C# - How can I get data from a registry key by a button.Name or button.Text?

Tags: c#, button, registry, registrykey

I am creating an app in C# and want to load a registry key that the name is equal to the button.Name (or button.Text if not possible). Can someone illuminate me how to do this please?

```
public OptionsForm(Button btn)

{
// RegBtnName = Registry key
// RegBtnLink = Registry Key
// btnX = button
btnX = btn;
// AppName = Textbox
AppName.Text = Registry.GetValue(RegBtnName,Convert.ToString(btnX.Name),"Not Found");
// AppDir = TextBox
AppDir.Text = Registry.GetValue(RegBtnLink,Convert.ToString(btnX.Name),"Not Found");

InitializeComponent();

}
```

Comment: check this if - `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx`

Comment: This is kind of asking, what you want to show in a MessageBox , you have typed in a textbox. Button.Name or Button.Text returns a string that your can read using Registry class.

Comment: I just posted the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use -

```
 string keyName = btn.Name;

 var value = Registry.GetValue(keyName, 
        "NoSuchName",
        "Return this default if NoSuchName does not exist.");

 MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)